# total commander adds a note to a file using tcimg and the parameters don't work correctly?

Tags: tags, file-manager, total-commander

total commander adds a note to a file using tcimg and the parameters don't work correctly：

comns=%L||[input=BOX50]||exect=$var_aa=*ArrayCreate(4)||$var_aa[1]='Program'||$var_aa[2]='Text'||$var_aa[3]='Conference'||$var_aa[4]=1000||* ArrayDisplay($var_aa)||exect=_ViewValues(ClipGet())||cliptext

Parameters cannot be run。